# Breakpad not building on ubuntu x64 for android

Tags: ubuntu, android-ndk, google-breakpad

I am trying to build breakpad using android ndk.

If I follow [**these instructions**](https://github.com/ashtom/breakapp):
i take this error on bottom.

Same error if i attach breakpad to my cocos2d-x project. Looks like it is ndk build problem.

1 time build mysteriously succeed, but i can't reproduce this.

My os are ubuntu 15x64,
android-sdk_r24.3.3-linux
android-ndk-r10e

```
/pr/breakapp$ ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-17 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: native <= native.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : breakpad_client <= crash_generation_client.cc
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : breakpad_client <= exception_handler.cc
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : breakpad_client <= minidump_descriptor.cc
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : breakpad_client <= log.cc
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : breakpad_client <= linux_dumper.cc
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.cc: In member function 'void google_breakpad::LinuxDumper::ParseLoadedElfProgramHeaders(Elf32_Ehdr*, uintptr_t, uintptr_t*, uintptr_t*, size_t*)':
jni/../../breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.cc:437:30: error: 'UINTPTR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
   const uintptr_t max_addr = UINTPTR_MAX;
                              ^
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/breakpad_client/src/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Replacing   APP_CPPFLAGS  := -stdc++11 with  APP_CPPFLAGS  := -std=gnu++11 in application.mk fixed problem

Answer (score 1):

I think define `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS`

for example like `APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++11 -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` in your `Application.mk`

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

to android/google_breakpad/Android.mk should fix the problem